# Retrieve the base url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am working on rails 2.3.11 .. and running my rails application with -P blogs

and the url will be like `http://localhost:3000/application_name`.

How to retrieve the above url inside the javascript of my rails view file

Please give suggestions

EDIT

localhost:3000/application_name is the base_url all over the app. I have a javascript with $.ajax with :url with "controller/action" which is not loading properly for the reason that its taking the loading page ctrllr as the ctrllr and not taking the ctrllr from the one i gave in the javascript .

Comment: which rails version are you using?

Comment: I am not sure but try adding `ActionController::AbstractRequest.relative_url_root = "/application_name"` in your `environment.rb`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you use

```
<%= root_url %>
```

Answer (score 1):

In rails basically every request specific can be found in `request`. Putting a`request.inspect` may give you insight to this.

If you just need the path in your javascript, the file needs to be an erb (e.g. something.js.erb). then it would just be `<%= blogs_path %>`.

If you're talking about the assets/javascripts/sprockets feature in the new rails, I don't know because I haven't used that yet.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/application_name is the base_url all over the app. I have a javascript with $.ajax with :url with "controller/action" which is not loading properly for the reason that its taking the loading page ctrllr as the ctrllr and not taking the ctrllr from the one i gave in the javascript .